# How to deal with Split Brain with an cluster have the two number of nodes?

Tags: cluster-computing, heartbeat, pacemaker

I am leaning some basic concept of cluster computing and I have some questions to ask.

According to [this article:](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/_perform_a_failover.html)

If a cluster splits into two (or more) groups of nodes that can no longer communicate with each other (aka.partitions), quorum is used to prevent resources from starting on more nodes than desired, which would risk data corruption.
A cluster has quorum when more than half of all known nodes are online in the same partition, or for the mathematically inclined, whenever the following equation is true:

**`total_nodes < 2 * active_nodes`**

For example, if a 5-node cluster split into 3- and 2-node paritions, the 3-node partition would have quorum and could continue serving resources. If a 6-node cluster split into two 3-node partitions, neither partition would have quorum; pacemaker’s default behavior in such cases is to stop all resources, in order to prevent data corruption.

**Two-node clusters are a special case**. 
By the above definition, a two-node cluster would only have quorum when both nodes are running. This would make the creation of a two-node cluster pointless

**Questions:**

From above,I came out with some confuse, why we can not stop all cluster resources like “**6-node cluster**”?What`s the special lies in the two node cluster?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that a two node cluster can only have quorum when they are in communication. Thus if the cluster was to split, using the default behavior, the resources would stop.

The solution is to not use the default behavior. Simply set Pacemaker to `no-quorum-policy=ignore`. This will instruct Pacemaker to continue to run resources even when quorum is lost.

...But wait, now what happens if the cluster communication is broke but both nodes are still operational. Will they not consider their peers dead and both become the active nodes? Now I have two primaries, and potentially diverging data, or conflicts on my network, right? This issue is addressed via STONITH. Properly configured STONITH will ensure that only one node is ever active at a given time and essentially prevent split-brains from even occurring.

An excellent article further explaining STONITH and it's importance was written by LMB back in 2010 here: http://advogato.org/person/lmb/diary/105.html